# ld: error: section: .data.rel.ro is not contiguous with other relro sections

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ld

I am using `-ffunction-sections` and `-gc-sections` options to optimize application, but ld fails to link with errors:

```
/home/yunxing.cyx/china-gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/collect2
-plugin /home/yunxing.cyx/china-gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/liblto_plugin.so
-plugin-opt=/home/yunxing.cyx/china-gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
-plugin-opt=-fresolution=/.vos/.ob-compile/tmp/yunxing.cyx/ccRgBV8r.res
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -shared -o libmyapp.so -z noexecstack /lib/../lib64/crti.o /home/yunxing.cyx/china-gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtbeginS.o @/.vos/.ob-compile/tmp/yunxing.cyx/ccX1Yrmq
-L/home/yunxing.cyx/work/myapp/rpm/.compile -L/home/yunxing.cyx/china-gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0
-L/home/yunxing.cyx/china-gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64
-L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/home/yunxing.cyx/china-gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../.. @/.vos/.ob-compile/tmp/yunxing.cyx/ccvpSZzo
-lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh /home/yunxing.cyx/china-gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtendS.o /lib/../lib64/crtn.o                       

ld: error: section: .data.rel.ro is not contiguous with other relro sections 
ld: error: section: .dynamic is not contiguous with other relro sections 
ld: error: section: .got is not contiguous with other relro sections 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[2]: *** [src/myserver/libmyapp.so] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [src/myserver/CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/all] Error 2 
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... 
[100%] Built target myapp_static 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `glibc` dynamic loader supports only one `relro` section, so the only possible solution I can think of (apart from not using `-ffunction-sections` or disabling PIE entirely) is to disable [relro hardening](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/hardening-elf-binaries-using-relocation-read-only-relro): `-Wl,-z,norelro`

---

As to the reasons why, if we check [`dl-support.c`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/f4f3b09111e9fa38fd485979a3e40b6cfa6a757d/elf/dl-support.c#L389) we see code like

```
  if (_dl_phdr != NULL)
    for (const ElfW(Phdr) *ph = _dl_phdr; ph < &_dl_phdr[_dl_phnum]; ++ph)
      switch (ph->p_type)
    {
    // . . .
    case PT_GNU_RELRO:
      _dl_main_map.l_relro_addr = ph->p_vaddr;
      _dl_main_map.l_relro_size = ph->p_memsz;
      break;
    }

  /* Setup relro on the binary itself.  */
  if (_dl_main_map.l_relro_size != 0)
    _dl_protect_relro (&_dl_main_map);
```

So only the last `PT_GNU_RELRO` PHDR will be protected. Knowing this, LD [throws](https://reviews.llvm.org/D40359) an error, to prevent a potential security issue.

A pull request to `glibc` to improve `relro` handling is always welcome.

Comment: any document say this constraint ?